# AudioKit engine failing on physical device Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=-10875

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, audiokit

I'm using the latest AudioKit (5), and have got it to pretty much work to my liking on the device simulator. Issue is that on my physical device (iphone x / ios 14), the engine.start() is failing.

General logic on `viewDidAppear`:

```
private func startEngine() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord)
            try engine.start()
        } catch let err {
            print("START ENGINE FAILED: ", err)
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=-10875 "(null)" UserInfo={failed call=err = AUGraphParser::InitializeActiveNodesInOutputChain(ThisGraph, kOutputChainOptimizedTraversal, *GetOutputNode(), isOutputChainActive)}
```

Would appreciate any help / ideas about this!

Thanks

Comment: You should activate your audio session before starting the audio engine.

Comment: I added and now call `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: AVAudioSession.SetActiveOptions.notifyOthersOnDeactivation)`  before, however same issue @RhythmicFistman

Comment: I set the session as active in `viewWillAppear` and start the engine in `viewDidAppear` @RhythmicFistman

Comment: @RhythmicFistman ok, some progress - it now works after I pop and then push the view controller with this logic. It makes me think it is related to the session as you mentioned, might need to start it off before

Comment: @RhythmicFistman was relatd to that - thanks. Needed to set up the correct settings

Comment: Please add your answer below and accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently my session wasn't active and set to the correct playback mode.

It is important to do so on appDidFinishLaunching or way before you expect to show your recording/playback screen.

```
do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord)
        } catch(let error) {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```